# How to make shortcut link for a website for each browser?

Tags: windows-xp, internet, browser

I want to make a shortcut link for same website for each browser is it possible.

For example:

I have 5 link shortcut on windows desktop for **Superuser.com** and PC has all browsers installed.

**Upon double clicking on shortcut:**

Shortcut one should be open in IE (Which is default browser)

Shortcut two should be open in Firefox

Shortcut two should be open in Safari

Shortcut two should be open in Opera

Answer (score 3):

Create a shortcut to each browser and go to the Shortcut tab of its Properties dialog. Make sure the path to the executable is in double-quotes in the Target field, and append the URL as a command line argument.

Alternatively, create a URL shortcut to [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) (or wherever) and drag it to each browser shortcut.